# Porque uma classe interna pode ser static e uma externa não?

Tags: java

É possível ter uma classe interna static:

```
public class ClasseExterna{
    public static class ClasseInterna(){
    }
}
```

E não é possível ter uma classe externa static:

```
public static class ClasseExterna{
    public static class ClasseExterna(){
    }
}
```

Qual a diferença entre uma situação e outra?

Comment: Sinceramente, nunca use uma classe interna. É uma aberração à orientação de objetos. Eu nem sabia que Java deixava fazer isso, pensava que fosse só no C#...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`static` significa que algo pertence diretamente a classe e que não precisa de uma instância dessa classe para poder acessá-lo.

O que pode ser estático:

- Métodos;
- Atributos; e
- Classes aninhadas.

#### Classe Aninhada Estática x Classe Aninhada Não Estática

Comparando duas classes, uma estática e outra não, porém ambas aninhadas, perceberemos o que significa a definição de estático, que eu citei acima:

```
class Externa {
    static class Estatica {
        void imprime() {
            System.out.println("método da classe aninhada estática");
        }
    }
    class NaoEstatica {
        void imprime() {
            System.out.println("método da classe aninhada NÃO estática");
        }   
    }
}

class TesteNestedClasses {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * repare que para criar uma instancia da classe estatica não foi necessário
         * criar uma instância da classe Externa
         */
        Externa.Estatica estatica = new Externa.Estatica();
        estatica.imprime();

        /*
         * não é possível criar uma classe não estática sem uma instancia da classe Externa
         */
        //Externa.NaoEstatica naoEstatica = new Externa.NaoEstatica(); //ERRADO!!!
        Externa externa = new Externa();
        Externa.NaoEstatica naoEstatica = externa.new NaoEstatica(); 
        naoEstatica.imprime();
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> método da classe aninhada estática
>   método da classe aninhada NÃO estática

Não podemos ter uma classe externa (ou seja, não aninhada) do tipo estático pois conforme a definição, estático é aquilo que pode ser acessado diretamente pela classe, sem a necessidade de uma instância, logo, se a classe não é aninhada a quem ela pertenceria se ela fosse estática? Não faz sentido algo assim, portanto não existe como implementar algo de tal maneira.

Answer (score 7):

Apenas classes declaradas dentro de outras (conhecidas com *classes-membro*) podem ser declaradas `static`. Classes *top-level*, anônimas ou locais (i.e., declaradas dentro de métodos) não podem.

Faz sentido: em Java, o modificador `static` é usado para modificar a relação de alguma entidade (classe, método, atributo) com a *classe* que a possui. Geralmente o modificador quer dizer que a entidade pertence, ou tem acesso, à classe a que pertence mas não às *instâncias* desta classe. Se uma classe é *top-level*, ela não é possuída por nenhuma outra: como poderia ser `static`, então?

Agora, a questão crucial é: o que o modificador `static` faz em classes-membro?

## Duas definições

A diferença entre uma classe-membro estática e uma classe-membro não-estática é sutil. Se fosse para defini-la em uma expressão bem abstrata, eu diria que

> - Toda instância de classes-membro não-estáticas está associada a uma instância da classe externa.
> - Instâncias de classes-membro estáticas *não estão associadas* a uma instância da classe externa alguma.

A conclusão prática disto é que instâncias de classes não-estáticas podem acessar diretamente os atributos e métodos (tanto estáticos quanto não-estáticos) da instância a que está associada. Instâncias de classes estáticas não podem acessar atributos e métodos não-estáticos de instância alguma da classe externa - somente os atributos estáticos da classe externa lhe são diretamente acessíveis.

Ok, isto é muito abstrato. Vamos ~concretar~ o conceito.

## O que só podemos fazer com classes não-estáticas

As classes não-estáticas estão sempre atreladas a uma instância da classe exterior. Por isso, podemos recuperar valores desta instância. Considere a classe exemplo abaixo, onde temos tanto uma classe estática e uma não-estática:

```
public class OuterClass {

    public static class StaticClass {}

    public class NonStaticClass {}

    private int field;

    public OuterClass(int field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass obj1 = new OuterClass(1);
        OuterClass obj2 = new OuterClass(2);
    }
}
```

Ok, agora vou adicionar à `NonStaticClass` um método que retorne o valor de `field` da instância de `OuterClass`. Se fosse para pegar a instância de `NonStaticClass`, usaríamos `this`. Para pegar a instância exterior, colocamos `OuterClass.this`:

```
    public class NonStaticClass {
            public int getOuterField() {
                    return OuterClass.this.field;
            }
    }
```

Agora, vamos imprimir, no construtor de `OuterClass`, o valor retornado por `NonStaticClass.getOuterField()`:

```
    public OuterClass(int field) {
            this.field = field;
            System.out.println(new NonStaticClass().getOuterField());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            OuterClass obj1 = new OuterClass(1);
            OuterClass obj2 = new OuterClass(2);
    }
}
```

Se eu executar essa classe, o resultado vai ser:

```
1
2
```

Note que o método `NonStaticClass.getOuterField()` retorna o valor do campo da instância em que foi chamado. Isto só é possível porque a instância de `NonStaticClass` conhece a instância de `OuterClass`.

## O que não podemos fazer com classes não-estáticas

Uma consequência disso é que não posso usar classes não-estáticas dentro de métodos estáticos. Por exemplo, não posso fazer isso:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass obj1 = new OuterClass(1);
        OuterClass obj2 = new OuterClass(2);

        // A linha abaixo não compila
        // NonStaticClass nonStaticClassInstance = new NonStaticClass();
    }
```

Por que não? Porque toda instância de `NonStaticClass` deve estar ligada a uma instância de `OuterClass`, mas o método `main(String[])` é  estático, não está "ligado" a nenhuma instância de `OuterClass`. É a mesma razão pela qual não podemos usar `this` dentro de um método estático. Contudo, podemos criar uma nova instância de `NonStaticClass` em um método estático (ou mesmo em outra classe) a partir de uma instância de `OuterClass`:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass obj1 = new OuterClass(1);
        OuterClass obj2 = new OuterClass(2);

        // A linha abaixo compila
        NonStaticClass instance = obj2.new NonStaticClass();
        // Imprimirá "2"
        System.out.println(instance.getOuterField());
   }
```

Outra consequência de se usar uma classe não-estática é que ela não pode ter campos ou métodos estáticos. Confesso que não entendo bem a razão disso, mas certamente não é algo que faz falta.

## O que só podemos fazer com classes estáticas

Classes estáticas, por sua vez, *não* precisam de uma instância da classe exterior. Uma consequência disso é que podem ser usadas em métodos estáticos sem *enclosing instances*:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // A linha abaixo compila
    StaticClass instance2 = new StaticClass();
}
```

Na verdade, se forem públicas, as classes estáticas podem ser usadas até por outras classes, de maneira bem semelhante às classes *top-level*. Normalmente, aliás, são usadas assim:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass.StaticClass obj1 = new OuterClass.StaticClass();

        // Classes não-estáticas públicas também podem ser usadas, mas
        // sempre atreladas a uma instância da classe externa.
        OuterClass outerClass = new OuterClass(3);
        OuterClass.NonSTaticClass obj2 = outerClass.new NonStaticClass();
    }
}
```

## O que não podemos fazer com classes estáticas

Como instâncias de classes estáticas não estão ligadas a instâncias da classe externa, elas não podem acessar campos e métodos destas instâncias:

```
private static class StaticClass {
    // O método abaixo não compila
    // public int getOuterField() {
    //     return field;
    // }
}
```

Por outro lado, tanto classes estáticas quanto classes não-estáticas podem acessar campos e métodos *estáticos* da classe externa, já que estes campos e métodosã ãno so ligados a uma instância específica:

```
private int field;
private static int staticField = 0;

private static class StaticClass {
    public int getStaticOuterField() {
        return staticField;
    }
    // O método abaixo não compila
    // public int getOuterField() {
    //      return field;
    // }
}

private class NonStaticClass {
    // O método abaixo compila
    public int getStaticOuterField() {
        return staticField;
    }
    // O método abaixo compila
    public int getOuterField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

Na prática, isto torna as classes estáticas praticamente equivalentes a classes *top-level*.

## Para que servem classes estáticas, então?

O principal motivo para se usar classes estáticas é estruturação de código.

Suponha que você tenha uma classe `Connection` como a abaixo:

```
public class Connection {
    public List getResult() throws ConnectionException {
        // Faz algo
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ela precisa de uma exceção específica para ela. Esta exceção poderia ser criada em outro pacote, mas muitos desenvolvedores gostam de declará-la dentro da própria classe, para manter a coesão:

```
public class Connection {
    public static class ConnectionException extends Exception {}    

    public List getResult() throws ConnectionException {
            // Faz algo
            return null;
    }
}
```

Pode parecer meio complicado, mas há vantagens:

- A nova classe terá acesso aos atributos e métodos privados da classe externa, reduzindo a necessidade de getters e setters.
- Incentiva modularização: um pedaço de um algoritmo poderia ser extraído em uma classe, mas criar outro arquivo complicaria seu código. Se você pode criar esta classe dentro da outra, já simplifica.
- Ajuda na coesão: a classe extraída ficará "colada" no código mais relevante, assim como a exceção acima.
- Como classes internas geralmente não são relevantes para outras partes do programa, criá-las como classes privadas favorece o encapsulamento

## Para que servem classes não-estáticas?

Na minha experiência, classes não-estáticas são menos comuns. Mesmo quando existem, poderiam ser substituídas por classes estáticas. Ainda assim, podem ser úteis para criar objetos que são intimamente ligados à instância externa.

Um bom exemplo talvez sejam iteradores. Considere a classe abaixo, que permite usar arrays como se fossem listas:

```
public class ArrayEnclosingList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

    private T array[]; 

    public ArrayEnclosingList(T[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

    public int size() {
        return array.length;
    }
}
```

`AbstractList` já fornece um método `iterator()`, mas podemos querer sobrescrevê-lo (frequentemente para otimizá-lo). No nosso caso, poderíamos fazer algo como:

```
public class ArrayEnclosingList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

    private T array[]; 

    // ...

    private class ArrayEnclosingListIterator implements Iterator<T> {

        private int pointer = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return pointer < array.length;
        }

        public T next() {
            return array[pointer++];
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ArrayEnclosingListIterator();
    }
}
```

Note como os métodos de `ArrayEnclosingListIterator` podem acessar `array`. Isto só é possível porque `ArrayEnclosingListIterator` é uma classe-membro não-estática. Daria para fazer isso com uma classe que naõ fosse interna? Certamente, mas iria complicar um tanto:

```
public class ArrayEnclosingListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private int pointer = 0;
    // Um atributo a mais
    private ArrayEnclosingList<T> list;

    // É preciso passar a instância da lista na mão
    public ArrayEnclosingListIterator(ArrayEnclosingList<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        // Agora o array da lista deve ser acessível
        return pointer < list.getArray().length; 
    }

    public T next() {
        // Agora o array da lista deve ser acessível
        return list.getArray()[pointer++];
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Neste caso, como o iterador é intimamente ligado ao iterável, a vantagem de pô-lo como classe-membro é evidente.