# Vetor em Java com campos em cada Celula

Tags: java, array

Eu to fazendo um trabalho em java e preciso saber como eu faço uma estrutura parecida com um Struct do C, onde cada célula do vetor tem 3 campos, exemplo vetor[i].idade , vetor[i].altura...
Se alguém puder me mostrar um código de uma estrutura ja implementada em java.

Agradeço desde já.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Ex6 {
public class Crianca{
    int Sexo, tempoVida;
    public Crianca(int Sexo, int tempoVida){
        this.Sexo = Sexo;
        this.tempoVida = tempoVida;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int numCriancas,contadorM = 0,contadorF = 0,contadorP = 0,leitorSexo,leitorTempo;
    Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Quantas crianças nasceram durante esse periodo: ");
    numCriancas = leitor.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < numCriancas; i++){
        ArrayList<Crianca> elemento = new ArrayList<Crianca>(numCriancas);
        System.out.println("A " + (i+1) + "º nascida é do sexo: ");
        System.out.println("1- Masculino");
        System.out.println("2- Feminino");
        leitorSexo = leitor.nextInt();
        if(leitorSexo == 1){
            contadorM++;
        }else{
            contadorF++;
        }
        System.out.println("Tempo de vida (em meses):");
        leitorTempo = leitor.nextInt();
        if(leitorTempo < 24){
            contadorP++;
        }
        Crianca elemento = new Crianca(leitorSexo,leitorTempo);

    }
    System.out.println("Das crianças que morreram:");
    System.out.println(contadorM+" Eram do sexo masculino.");
    System.out.println(contadorF+" Eram do sexo feminino.");
    System.out.println(contadorP+" Morreram antes de 24 meses de vida.");

    leitor.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Você já conhece o conceito de classes?

Comment: Mais ou menos cara, por isso to aqui perguntando, eu fiz uma classe com um metodo construtor e criei um ArrayList dessa classe mas ta acusando erro e não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Hehe eu já estava escrevendo uma resposta bem basicona, mas se você já sabe o básico então poste seu código, pra gente te ajudar a achar o problema dele. Quando mais **contexto** você colocar na pergunta melhores as respostas que poderá ter, pois assim a gente fica sabendo o que você já sabe e o que ainda não. (P.S. Poste também o erro que está tendo; se for uma *stack trace*, poste ela toda, não só a última linha)

Comment: Postei o Erro que da é Variavel Local Duplicada, porem se eu mudo o nome da o erro

    Multiple markers at this line
 - No enclosing instance of type Ex6 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Ex6 (e.g. x.new 
  A() where x is an instance of Ex6).
 - The value of the local variable novoelemento is not used
 - Duplicate local variable elemento

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta mais detalhada, mas para uma solução rápida: 1) você tem duas variáveis com o nome `elemento`, mude o nome de uma delas; 2) declare `Crianca` como `public static class Crianca`.

Comment: Poxa mano vc fez magica :), deu tudo certim por aqui, vlw mesmo, se tiver como te "Comendar" me fala ai q vc merece meu like.

Comment: Postei uma resposta explicando melhor. Se achar que ela soluciona seu problema, você tem a opção de ["aceitá-la"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Quando você tiver 10 pontos ou mais nesse site, você também poderá [votar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) nas perguntas/respostas que você achar úteis/relevantes.

Answer (score 2):

Em Java toda classe - inclusive aquela que possui o método `main` - pode ser usada para criar objetos. Isso significa que mesmo sua classe `Ex6` *poderia* ser usada para se criar um objeto (ainda que na prática isso não sirva pra nada):

```
Ex6 obj = new Ex6();
```

Tudo o que se refere a um objeto - campos, métodos, construtor e **classes internas** - só pode ser acessado tendo por base um objeto. Por exemplo, não faz sentido você fazer:

```
Crianca.Sexo = 10; // 10 é o sexo de qual criança?
```

O correto é:

```
Crianca fulano = new Crianca();
fulano.Sexo = 10; // 10 é o sexo da criança "fulano"
```

Por essa razão, quando você declarou `Crianca` dentro da classe `Ex6`, o Java interpretou como se essa fosse uma classe específica de um objeto do `Ex6`, que só existe "amarrada" a um objeto `Ex6`. Como não há nenhuma instância da classe `Ex6`, a classe `Crianca` não pode ser acessada.

### Membros *static*

Quando um componente - de novo, campos, métodos e classes internas - pertence **à classe**, e não **ao objeto**, ele deve ser declarado junto com a palavra-chave `static`. Seu método `main`, por exemplo, já recebe essa palavra (pois ele pode ser chamado sem nenhum objeto de `Ex6` pré-existente). Se você pretende declarar a classe `Crianca` dentro de `Ex6` (e não em um arquivo separado, como é o mais comum), então você precisa declará-la dessa forma:

```
public static class Crianca
```

[Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23272/215) tem algumas informações adicionais sobre como classes internas estáticas funcionam.

Comment: Entendi, me ajudou muito, só mais uma duvida e se eu quiser criar tipo um vetor onde cada elemento do vetor contenha os elementos da classe onde eu possa percorrer este vetor com um for checando quantas crianças são do sexo masculino por Ex: if(fulano[i].sexo == 1)...

Comment: @JoãoCarlos É mais ou menos igual ao que você fez com `ArrayList`. As diferenças são: 1) o modo de declarar - `Crianca[] vetor;` cria uma referência nula (`null`); `Crianca[] vetor = new Crianca[10];` cria um array de crianças com tamanho 10, todos os elementos nulos. 2) Você precisa preencher esse vetor com crianças (em Java todo objeto é criado no heap, nunca no stack, como pode ser feito em C). ex.: `vetor[0] = new Crianca(...)`. 3) Você pode descobrir o tamanho do vetor usando a propriedade `length`. Ex.: `for ( int i = 0 ; i < vetor.length ; i++ ) if ( vetor[i].sexo == 1 ) ...`.

Comment: P.S. Acho que essa linha precisa ser declarada **fora** do `for`, não? `ArrayList<Crianca> elemento = new ArrayList<Crianca>(numCriancas);` Do jeito que você está fazendo, ele vai criar um `ArrayList` novo a cada passo do loop.

Comment: Sim ele é declarado fora, ele ta la dentro para efeitos de teste somente. :) Obrigado pelas dicas, me ajudou muito.